# Athena String vs List datatype

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I need some help to make a decision as to which data type to use for a column in Athena. I have a list of items and I am wondering storing it as an ARRAY or string makes more sense performance-wise.

For example:
user_cities

| user | cities |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | ["New York", "Dallas"] |
| 02 | ["Chicago", "New York"] |

Most queries would be to find the user for a city as of now.

```
select * from user_cities where contains(cities, "New York")
```

I know that if cities is a string we can turn it into an array via casting it to JSON and then to array.

But which one makes more sense for future-proofing and performance-wise?

Comment: Depends on your usage. If you fetch whole list of cities all the times, then performance difference will be minor. Where as if you dice like only "Dallas" from cities, then Array datatype is the winner. Also, Array supports nested array, creation of maps, aggregation etc.  More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-arrays.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best performance for your query would be if you will keep 3NF:

`user_cities (User, City)` relation

and query like this:

```
select * from user_cities where city="New York"
```

If you want to compare array vs concatenated string then it will be not much difference. If it is already array, then you do not need to split it, from this perspective array is better. But it does not make significant difference in performance. If you want to add city to a user you need to update the array, from this perspective storing it as (user, city) is better, also it can be indexed much better in columnar formats and compressed far much better and if you want to query all users which have New York city then (user, city) is better.

So, I would recommend in this order of preference:

1. user, city: multiple rows per user
2. `user, array<city>`
3. user, string concatenated

Comment: Data is never going to be updated. Also, the data will be stored in the parquet file. so I am thinking of using LIST data type for parquet and then Athena can read the cities as ARRAY.  multiple rows per user can't be done - I am storing the API endpoints and the list of params sent in the body and we also want to count the number of times API endpoint is called. Multiple rows will produce the wrong result.